# Laravel with Vite + React Unexpected reserved word 'interface'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, laravel

I have a very strange problem in my Laravel project with Vite + React.

When trying to create a simple interface like below, I get the error

> Unexpected reserved word 'interface'.

```
interface Email {
  label: string;
  text: string;
};
```

If I run vite using "npm run dev" I get this error, if i run it with "npm run build" it detects the typescript normally and compiles the code.

With **npm run build**
[image]

With **npm run dev**
[image]

My project use:

- Laravel
- Vite
- React

I've tried all the corrected ways, but I can't, TypeScript dont compile.

Could it be something related to the need to compile TypeScript every time?

I need real-time debugging.

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        proxy: {
          '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:8000', // Endereço do servidor Laravel
            changeOrigin: true,
            rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
          },
        },
    },
    esbuild: {
      loader: 'tsx',
    },
    build: {
        chunkSizeWarningLimit: 2000
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
      esbuildOptions: {
          loader: {
              '.js': 'jsx',
              '.ts': 'tsx',
          },
      },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.jsx'
        ]),
        react(),
    ],
});
```

**package.json** from root dir

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.4",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.5",
        "vite": "^4.4.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.2",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.3",
        "@mui/material": "^5.14.4",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
        "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "react-device-detect": "^2.2.3",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-google-recaptcha": "^3.1.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
        "styled-components": "^6.0.6",
        "typescript": "^5.2.2",
        "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.1"
    }
}
```

**package.json** from vite-project

```
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.10"
  }
}
```

Thanks.

**#EDIT**

@Jacob Smit solved with this:

> change filetype to TSX not JSX.

Works but i get this error:

> 'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module

Solved with:

> import React from 'react';

But, now my console.log trigger two times:

```
import React from 'react'
import { HomeView } from "../Views/Workspace/HomeView";
import { RegisterView } from "../Views/Workspace/RegisterView";

interface Email {
  label: string;
  text: string;
};

const mail: Email = { label: "subject", text: "mail" };

function WorkspaceHome() {
    console.log(mail);

    return (
      <HomeView 
        teste="Home View funcionando !" 
      />
    );
}
```

[image]

Comment: change filetype to TSX not JSX.

Comment: Change all project .jsx files to tsx ??

Comment: you don't have to do all of them, but any that use types or interfaces (which are part of Typescript not JavaScript) need to be TSX

Comment: Change from JSX to TSX works but get error: "'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module", so i added import React from 'react' and works, thanks for help.

Comment: Perfect, but last doubt now my console.log trigger two time...

Comment: in a `useEffect`? This is done in development when using strictmode. It's done so that react can pick up errors with your hooks. In production they will only run once. Here is a [quick link from google](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/why-is-my-useeffect-hook-running-twice-in-react) that explains it in more detail or there are a number of questions on here that will answer it if you search.

Comment: Works, thanks for help.